# Accept or Decline Apple Calendar Event (.ics)

Tags: ios, events, icalendar

I have a PHP script I've setup to generate an .ics file and email it to a person. The generated ics file works as intended in Microsoft Outlook 2010 but not on iOS devices. When the calendar event is launched in Outlook, the user is asked whether to accept or decline the event however when the user launches the same ics file on their iPhone, iOS only offers them to "Add to Calendar."

[image]

How can I force or make iOS ask the user to accept or decline the event?

Here's my mocked up ics file:

> ```
> BEGIN:VCALENDAR
> METHOD:REQUEST
> VERSION:2.0
> PRODID:-//TEST INC//TEST//EN
> BEGIN:VEVENT
> DTSTAMP:1402101843
> SEQUENCE:0
> UID:539236231203d
> ORGANIZER:MAILTO:test@blahblah.com
> ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:test@blahblah.com
> DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20140612
> DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20140613
> CATEGORIES:MEETING
> CLASS:PUBLIC
> SUMMARY:Meeting Test
> DESCRIPTION:Test
> X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN"">
>                   <html><body><b>Test</b>
>                   </body></html>
> END:VEVENT
> END:VCALENDAR
> ```

I guess I'm missing something in my ics file to communicate with Apple's standards?
I looked over at [iCalendar .ics accept/decline on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515534/icalendar-ics-accept-decline-on-ios) but no solution was found.

Thanks!

Comment: For googlers like me: X-ALT-DESC is not supported as of iOS13.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue (Outlook has Accept/Decline but iOS doesn't) and was able to fix it by adding the ORGANIZER line.  It appears your syntax may be wrong.  You have a colon after ORGANIZER instead of a semicolon.  You may also need to fix the capitalization of mailto (should be MAILTO) in the ATTENDEE line.

Comment: It doesn't fix the issue. It appears that the AppleID must match the ATTENDEE's email in order for iOS to display Accept/Decline.