# iCal .ics file : allow user to confirm

Tags: icalendar

While downloading an ICS file on IOS the event gets added automatically to my calendar.

Basically the file downloads and it briefly shows the event on the calendar (half a second) and then it automatically closes.

The good thing is that the event is added correctly to my calendar; however, I would like the user to be able to review the event and then be able to click the OK button to confirm adding to their calendar.

This is my .ics file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:Our Monthly meeting will be awesome this month!
DTSTART:20180711T190000
DTEND:20180711T200000
LOCATION:5 Lions Dr. Lake Zurich IL 60047 
SUMMARY:Monthly Meeting
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
UID:rk7k5kp4d3h
DTSTAMP:20180708T190936
```

I've been trying to find out if there is a flag to control this automatic closing of the calendar, but I cannot find anything.

Does anybody know how I can accomplish this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, nobody answered, but I figured it out. For anyone having this issue. Your line endings need to be `\r\n` and not `\n`

Comment: Hm that may be working, but it's not the purpose of that part of the VEVENT.  Other posts that may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515534/icalendar-ics-accept-decline-on-ios and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091154/accept-or-decline-apple-calendar-event-ics#comment39641005_25394228

Comment: Thanks. Yes it turned out the issue was my line endings. Had to change '\n' to '\r\n'